# Android : Camera's dimensions doesn't match screen's dimensions

Tags: java, android, camera, android-linearlayout

I've written my own camera activity, I show the photo's live preview in a `FrameLayout`, but the live picture doesn't seem natural, it's a bit tall, I think it's because the dimensions of the `FrameLayout` doesn't match the camera's dimensions. what should I do to fix it ?

Here is the xml file of the camera activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.86" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="capture"
    android:text="Capture" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_accept"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Accept"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:onClick = "accept" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_retake"
    android:layout_width="107dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Retake" 
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:onClick = "retake"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem can be solved like this :

```
        Parameters cameraParam =  mCamera.getParameters() ;
        double ratio = (double)cameraParam.getPictureSize().height / (double)cameraParam.getPictureSize().width  ;
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        try
        {
            display.getSize(size);
        }
        catch(java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore)
        {
            size.x = display.getWidth(); 
            size.y = display.getHeight() ;
        }
        int width = size.y;
        int height = size.x;
        previewParam.width =  width;
        previewParam.height = (int)(previewParam.width / ratio) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to scale the image that has been taken from the camera. You could try something like this :

```
private Bitmap scaleImage(ImageView imageView, String path) {
int targetWidth = imageView.getWidth();
int targetHeight = imageView.getHeight();

BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bitmapOptions);
int photoWidth = bitmapOptions.outWidth;
int photoHeight = bitmapOptions.outHeight;

int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoWidth / targetWidth, photoHeight / targetHeight);

bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
bitmapOptions.inPurgeable = true;

return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bitmapOptions);
```

}

Comment: No, The photo that has been taken from camera is fine, only the live picture that is shown in camera preview(before taking the picture) is a bit tall!

Comment: Is your code to open the camera similar to : 
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE_REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: You could refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Size.html

Comment: yes,
thanks a lot,
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5564589/ ,
and the xml is included in the question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25078/discussion-between-lokoko-and-navid777)